# The root of a complex number in a definite integral.

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, contour-integration

This integral, after calculation, contains the root of a complex number.

$$\int_{-7}^{3+2i}{\frac{dz}{(1-z)^{\frac{2}{3}}}} = 6-3\cdot(2-2i)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

What should I do to get one number in the answer, not many. In the problem statement it is said to consider $\sqrt[3]{8} = 2\space$. The Wolfram Mathematica package, when calculating this integral in the answer, gives one number.
[Wolfram solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvyG2.png)

Comment: $(1-z)^{2/3}$ is multivalued as well. If you define a holomorphic branch for the integrand then the result is uniquely determined.

Comment: @martin-r In the problem statement it is said to consider $8^{\frac{1}{3}} = 2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a branch cut along the positive real axis, therefore, the argument of a complex number $z$ is $\theta \in (0, 2 \pi)$. With this choice, we have the function inside integral sign holomorphic for all values of $z$ except for the points on the branch cut. By the fundamental theorem of Calculus for complex function:
$$\int_{-7}^{3+2i}{\frac{dz}{(1-z)^{\frac{2}{3}}}} = \frac{1}{3} (1-z)^{\frac{1}{3}} \Big|_{-7}^{3+2i} =  6-3\cdot(2-2i)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$